# variable voltage supply

Tags: voltage

Application - Dry burn heating coil.

Using a 3.7v battery I would like to heat/dry burn a coil in order to burn off accumulated residue on the coil from liquid that the coil is heating. I would like a circuit that will take 3.7v input and output between 2.5v and 3.5v which will vary automatically.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Input is 3.7v.
Resistance on average is 2.0 ohms.
I think amps is 1.85!!!

Thanks

Comment: How many amps??

Answer (score 1):

You want what is called a "buck regulator", like the [Maxim MAX1591](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1951-MAX1952.pdf):

[image]

It will take anything from 2.6 to 5.5 volts in, and output anywhere from 0.8 to the input voltage.  So in your case, V\$_{IN}\$ is 3.7v, and the output will be 2.5v to 3.5v at up to 2A.  The output voltage is set up by the two resistors between the output, FB and ground.  So you can either put a pot their, or if you want to control the output voltage from a microcontroller for example, you could use a digital pot.  The output

I am assuming your input voltage will remain above 3.5v.  (You didn't say whether you are using non-rechargeable batteries or rechargeable ones).  If the input voltage can fall below 3.5v, then you need a "buck-boost regulator" instead, like this [LTC3112](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3112fc.pdf):

[image]

In this case, V\$_{IN}\$ can be above or below the output voltage.  Current up to 2.5A.

Neither of these parts is available in through-hole versions, but I have tried to pick SMT parts that can be fairly easily soldered, i.e. avoiding BGA, WSON, DFN etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will give it a go.